# Learning Prerequisites for understanding & mastering Apache SOLR

Tags: apache, solr

I am Remedy developer in Solaris environment.
I have hands on knowledge on SQLand knowledge about CORE Java.
I would like to know what coding languages/tools or environments should i be familiar or thorough for understanding APACHE SOLR.
In other words what should i have strong knowledge on to be able to understand APache SOLR better.

Please advise!!
Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

To understand apache solr you should be familiar of following things,

- Search Engine Basics, How search engine works.
- Different techniques of searching , e.g Phonetic search, Stemming, Lemmatization etc
- Concept of inverted indexing

Answer (score 0):

Solr is developed in JAVA.

To understand it or to learn it refer the solr wiki or solr tutorial.

There is as such dependency. If you want to use it solr by DIH, then you have already mentioned that you have good SQL knowlege.

Refer the below links :

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/tutorial.html